How to dynamic generate a view when a list item got clicked
I have a list to represent a list of dates

It displays like in the upper side of screenshot
I'm wondering how can I click the another  date in the list and generate a dynamic view based on new date
my current code to generate all dates
func generateDateListView() -> some View{
        return ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
            HStack(spacing: 6){
                ForEach(1...7, id:\.self){ index in
                    if index == 2{
                        singlePickedDate(isSelected: true)
                    }
                    else{
                        singlePickedDate(isSelected: false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

I tried to do that with NavigationLink but it's not something I wanted, I dont want to route it  to another new page. Instead, I want to stay in same page, but changed the new clicked date with clicked view(the  white circle thingy) and generate the new content.
I think I may know how to generate the new content, but I just not sure how to select an item in the list

import SwiftUI

struct CalendarView: View {
    // Get current date information
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let currentDate = Date()

    // Define date formatter to display month
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM" // Display full month name
        return formatter
    }()

    // Calculate current week days
    var currentWeek: [Date] {
        let startOfWeek = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: currentDate))!
        return (0..<7).compactMap { calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeek) }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Display the current month name
            HStack {
                Text(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate))
                    .font(.title)
                    .bold()
                Spacer()

                // Calendar icon (you can use SF Symbols here)
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.yellow)

            // Display the days of the week
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(currentWeek, id: \.self) { date in
                    DayView(date: date, isToday: calendar.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: currentDate))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Ensure each day takes equal space
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}

// View for each day
struct DayView: View {
    let date: Date
    let isToday: Bool
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    // Date formatter to extract the day name and number
    let dayFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "E" // Day of the week as abbreviation
        return formatter
    }()

    let numberFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d" // Day number
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 4) {
            // Day of the week (e.g., Mon)
            Text(dayFormatter.string(from: date))
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .lineLimit(1) // Ensure day name stays in one line
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5) // Allow text to scale if needed to fit

            // Day number (e.g., 1)
            Text(numberFormatter.string(from: date))
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.top, 10)

            // Current day has a white circle around it
            if isToday {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                    .overlay(
                        Text(numberFormatter.string(from: date))
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    )
                    .padding(.top, -30)
            }
        }
        .padding(7)
        .background(isToday ? Color.black.opacity(0.3) : Color.clear) // Highlight current day with opaque background
        .cornerRadius(100)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CalendarView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
                .previewDevice("iPhone 14")
            ContentView()
                .previewDevice("iPhone SE (3rd generation)")
                .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
        }
    }
}


I implemented another example to demonstrate how I could dynamically distribute the 7 days on the screen (vertical or horizontal). This code needs to be improved (separate the responsibilities, date logic, views...). But I believe it should help.

If you agree that the previous answer solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer so that other devs who may have the same problem can know that this solution solved the problem.

@Hermogenes  Thank you for help. I can't emphasis how much you help me. Thank you a lot

I created the calendar in a different way to test the solution.
We have 7 days being displayed (the days of the current week).
I created a function that is executed when a day is selected.
This function has a date as a parameter (which will be the date of the selected day).
With the date of the selected day you can customize the new Day screen.
The code is below:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    @State private var showDayView: Bool = false
    @State private var offsetY: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack {
                // Header section
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("August")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .bold()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .padding()
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(Color.yellow)

                // Custom date picker (CalendarView)
                PickerDateView(selectedDate: $selectedDate) {
                    self.singlePickedDate(date: $0)
                }

                Spacer()
            }

            // DayView appears from bottom to top with swipe gesture support
            if showDayView {
                DayView(selectedDate: selectedDate, onClose: closeDayView)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom)) // Transition from bottom to top
                    .offset(y: offsetY)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                offsetY = value.translation.height
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                if value.translation.height > 100 {
                                    // Swipe down to close DayView
                                    closeDayView()
                                }
                                offsetY = 0
                            }
                    )
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }

    // Function to handle date selection
    func singlePickedDate(date: Date) {
        selectedDate = date
        withAnimation {
            showDayView = true
        }
    }

    // Function to close DayView
    func closeDayView() {
        withAnimation {
            showDayView = false
        }
    }

    // Function to go to the next day
    func goToNextDay() {
        if let nextDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: selectedDate) {
            selectedDate = nextDay
        }
    }

    // Function to go to the previous day
    func goToPreviousDay() {
        if let previousDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: selectedDate) {
            selectedDate = previousDay
        }
    }
}

// Custom date picker view (CalendarView)
struct PickerDateView: View {

    @Binding var selectedDate: Date
    var onDateSelected: (Date) -> Void

    let daysOfWeek: [String] = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 30) {
            ForEach(0..<7) { index in
                let day = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: index, to: startOfWeek())!
                VStack {
                    // Display day of the week
                    Text(daysOfWeek[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: day) - 1])
                        .font(.caption)
                        .fontWeight(selectedDate == day ? .bold : .regular)

                    // Display day number
                    Text(day, format: .dateTime.day())
                        .font(.body)
                        .fontWeight(selectedDate == day ? .bold : .regular)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .background(selectedDate == day ? Color.yellow.opacity(0.5) : Color.clear)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            onDateSelected(day)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 10)
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }

    // Function to get the start of the current week
    func startOfWeek() -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let today = Date()
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: today)
        return calendar.date(from: components) ?? today
    }
}

// View that displays the selected day with rounded corners on the top and swipe gestures
struct DayView: View {

    let selectedDate: Date
    let onClose: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Selected Date:")
                .font(.title)
            Text(selectedDate, style: .date)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(20, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight]) // Round only the top left and right corners
        .offset(y: 170) // Set the view to be 170px below the top of the screen
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.leading, .trailing, .bottom]) // Remove margins on sides and bottom
    }
}

// Extension to allow corner radius for specific corners
extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}

struct RoundedCorner: Shape {

    var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Thank your for your answer. I learned a lot from it. It is such a organized structure. I think it gonna take me a while to write some code like this. But I have a another quick question. I'm wondering how can you fit 7 date item in one line so evenly. I saw you add a frame with 30 width and 30 height. Where did you get this number ? Did you just calculate them?

In this example I just adjusted it to present it distributed on the screen (without any responsive or dynamic way). See another answer, please.
